# Ubuntu 14.04 repeats the background voice for every input

Tags: 14.04, accessibility

I have installed the Ubuntu 14.04 before a week, when ever I gave an input action it is repeated over male voice.

Example: if I press the F5 key then Ubuntu produce the male voice as "f5". If I open a new window it will read the all the options and inputs.

How can I disable this voice? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to System Preferences → Universal Access → Seeing tab
2. Turn Screen Reader `off`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To Turn on or off `Screen Reader` Press `Alt+Super+S`  OR

1. Go to `System Settings ...`
2. Select `Universal Access`
3. Select `Seeing` Tab
4. Turn off `Screen Reader`